# Error in getting continuous mean values using while loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop

I have a dataset which is stored in df variable.

On using the df.shape function is am getting the o/p as (1271,19)

```
df = data.copy()
cond = df["CELLNO"] == 1
df = df[cond]
df = df.reset_index()

df.shape
```

Output:

```
(1271, 19)
```

Table:

```
df
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tefQJ.png)

```
i = 0
j = 20
while j < df.shape[0]:
    
    data = df.copy()
    data_1 = data.loc[i:j]
    mean = np.mean(data_1.RATED_TORQUE_ACTUAL)
    mean_dec = round(mean, 2)
    mean_list.append(mean_dec)
    i += j + 1
    j += 20
print(mean_list)
```

But this while works fine for 2 values of calculating mean but later on it gives nan as o/p

Output:

```
[876.27, 873.22, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

I tried to look into my data, there are no cells which are null or empty

I want to take specific column mean of every 20 rows, and store it in a list. If there is any better solution other than this, that would also work

Datalink : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXHZ33pcoWZZWEZ0X5yvow-EDylTGY20/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Try `data_1 = data.iloc[i:j]` and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have edited my question and have attached an image of the data

Comment: @FanchenBao iloc is also not working, getting the same output

Comment: Since the third mean value is the first to show `nan`, can you provide the first 60 rows of your data?

Comment: how am I suppose to share the file @FanchenBao ?

Comment: You can put the file on a cloud storage and provide a link. Or, since the amount of data is not that big, you can simply copy the data in csv format and paste it directly in your question, preferably in a code block.

Comment: I have added the link of the data @FanchenBao

Comment: @ScottHunter I have provided the data as a link. You can access it now

Answer (score 1):

I could get the list now,

Since 'i' was incremented by 'i + j + 1' after 2 loops, the value of 'i' was more than that of 'j'

I have now incremented both 'i' and 'j' by 20

Thank you